# Adding checkboxes dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main category that consists of a row of checkboxes. In this main category, I have a button `Add Section`, which adds another row of checkboxes and keep adding another row of checkboxes after each click on the `Add Section`.

So, the main category is composed with a new input field as `input type="text" id="sup-title-1" class="sup-title js-sup-title" value="sup 1">` , the code as follows. And it also consists of checkboxes are dynamically added via a `for-loop`.

**This is the initial main category with static elements and dynamically generated checkboxes**

```
<div class="services-content sup-content">
    <div class="services__supnisation">
        <div class="services__supnisation-title">
            <input type="text" id="sup-title-1" class="sup-title js-sup-title" value="sup 1">
        </div>

        <div class="services-item js-splits-item">
            <ul>
                @{
                    int num = (int)TempData["Counter"];
                    int numOfCheckboxes = (4 * (num)) - 1;

                    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="sup-@j-1">
                            <label for="sup-@j-1"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>

            <div class="services-item__footer">
                <small class="services-item__availability">
                    <span class="title">Section 1</span>
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="services-actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn secondary-btn-border add-split-btn js-add-split mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                 Add Section
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- New Category should be added here -->

</div>
```

So now, when I hit the `Add Section` button, another row of checkboxes are dynamically created inside this main section using the same `for-loop` as per above.

Outside the main section, I have a button `Create New Category` that creates another main section. This is as per below:

**This is other main sections that will be generated dynamically**

```
 <div class="stepper__services">

        <div class="services-actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn secondary-btn-border js-create-sup mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Create New Category
            </button>


        </div>
    </div>

<script>

    $('.js-create-sup').click(function () {

        var count = 2;

        var supContent = `<div class="services__supnisation">

        <div class="services__supnisation-title">
            <input type="text" id="sup-title-`+count+`" class="sup-title js-sup-title" value="sup`+count+`">
        </div>

        <div class="services-item js-splits-item">
            <ul>
                @{
                    int num = (int)TempData["Counter"];
                    int numOfCheckboxes = (4 * (num)) - 1;

                    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="sup-@j-`+count+`">
                            <label for="sup-@j-`+count+`"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>

            <div class="services-item__footer">
                <small class="services-item__availability">
                    <span class="title">Section 1</span>
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="services-actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button secondary-btn secondary-btn-border add-split-btn js-add-split mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                 Add Section
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>`;

        $(supContent).last().clone().insertAfter($('.sup-content').last());

        count++;
    });

</script>
```

Now, the code for adding each sub-category within the main category is as per below. What the code is doing that it adds another row of checkboxes, and performs a validation on the checkboxes. It checks if the above checkbox in the row has already been checked. This works perfectly fines until I add another main category, which does not add the sub-category properly when I click the `Add Section` button within that main category in that main category. Note that currently each `sub-category` is dynamically added after `.js-splits-item`.

Please, can someone help me with this to get this working ? I am really struggling with this. I can provided additional details.

```
<script>
    var count = 1;

    $('.js-add-split').click(function () {
        count++;
        var splitContent = `<div class="services-item js-splits-item">
            <ul>
                @{
                    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCheckboxes; j++)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="sup-@j-`+count+`">
                            <label for="sup-@j-`+count+`"><i class="icon-tick" disabled></i></label>
                        </li>
                    }
                }

            </ul>

            <div class="services-item__footer">
                <small class="services-item__availability">
                    <span class="title">Section` + count + `</span>
                </small>

            </div>
        </div>`;

        $(splitContent).last().clone().insertAfter($('.js-splits-item').last());

        $('.js-splits-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); 
            var chk = $(this).is(":checked");            
            var obj = this;                            

            $('.js-splits-item').each(function () {         
                $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Does it seem like your js-add-split event handler is not being called on the dynamically created items?

Comment: Please see this, as I believe following this format may help with your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment if you need more help.

Comment: But in my case, I already have a `js-splits-item`. Also, other `js-splits-item` are being dynamically added. @Dan Orlovsky

Comment: Right - so the event handler will work with the one's that exist.  Not the new ones.  Try delegating your bindings.

Comment: How do to this ?

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of event delegation can be found here:
[jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and in the Stack Overflow answer provided in the comments: [Stack Overflow Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements).

The problem is you are using **Direct Binding** which means, you are binding directly to an element that exists on the DOM.  The issue you're facing is, you want to link events to elements that **don't yet exist**.  To accomplish this, you start by attaching the event handler to a higher-order component, and delegating down to the element you are seeking.

`$(document).on("click", ".js-add-split", function () { ...`

Notice - you use the `on()` jQuery method rather than `click()` directly, and we choose a higher-order component.  In this example, I used `document` - which is rather extreme, but hopefully you get the picture.